# Why is my H2 autoincrement column not rolling back after upgrading to Hibernate5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

Working on upgrading from Hibernate 3.6 to 5.2. Some old tests have stopped working, one of those are comparing max id in an autoincrement column before and after insert (max(id) before should be max(id)+1 after).

We are using H2 as an in-memory database, and we have not upgraded H2.

Our problem is that previously, when a test rolled back for some reason, the row in the database was of course deleted, but also the autoincrement column was reset, so if an insert is performed but failed (for example due to some constraint), the autoincrement ID generated would be the same next time.

After upgrading to 5, this is no longer the case and i cannot understand why.

We had to change the ID column from just

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

to

```
@GeneratedValue(     
    strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
    generator = "native")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "native",
    strategy = "native")
```

(Good explanation [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/))

I have tried to debugging the Hibernate "IdentifierGeneratorHelper", and it seems it just returns the int that comes up from H2 as a result of the insert. But H2 hasn't changed!

Pointers would be great.

**Disclaimer**: i know that you should not rely on autoincrement int values. These are old tests and i'm just trying to make sure i understand all changes that Hibernate5 brought.